# Unable to pay $5 to register as a Chrome Web Store developer

Tags: registration, chrome-web-store

I'm unable to pay $5 to register as a Web Store developer. It keeps giving me an error:

```
Uh oh. There was a problem.

We couldn't start your purchase because of a technical issue.

Details of the problem below:
There is an error in the setup for your purchase. Please contact the merchant about this issue.
```

I can see few discussions related to the same problem:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pkmiFvCypks

but unable to find a solution yet. Is anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Try contacting google helpdesk.